# How can I increase the length for the taxonomy term slug?

Tags: taxonomy, slug

I am trying to create a new term in topic taxonomy.
Since I am writing in Bangla Unicode instead of English, the slug is created with lesser/broken text.

Is there any hook to update the length for the taxonomy term slug?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default WordPress [sets the length of that field to 200](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/d5fd3bd4529e5a6e17bfd857279ae47363e5be2a/wp-admin/includes/schema.php#L65) when the database tables are created.

Now you could change that by running this SQL command in your console (change the tabe prefix to your setting, and make a backup first):

```
ALTER TABLE wp_terms MODIFY COLUMN slug VARCHAR(1000);
```

But … the nice name, the first field in your screenshot, has the same restriction, and it's not truncated. Also I don't see anything in the WordPress code that enforces a restriction on the slug before it is inserted into the database. It's possible I missed that in the callback hell that WP is.

So do a test run for this in a safe, exact copy of your site and see if it fixes your issue. Also make sure you don't insert invalid characters, because they *will* lead to truncated values. This can happen when you are using copy&paste from a software that isn't completely Unicode compatible, like Word.

The other "solution" is just to use shorter slugs.